# Format .NET Json Date in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

How can I format a JSON date that looks like this:
 /Date(1438956000000)/
into a Date in Angular JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an inline solution, this is a quick and dirty way to get it done using the inbuilt angular date filter:
`{{yourDateVariable.slice(6, -2) | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`
Would still be keen to see if anyone has build this into a directive to handle nulls etc.
Anyone?